# Unity3d Method Must Have a Return Type And Error CS0501

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial about voxel meshes and ran into an error that I did not expect. Here is the [tutorial](http://studentgamedev.blogspot.com/2013/08/VoxelTutP2.html), I am on the second part if you go and take a look at that. I also thought maybe this is a unity version issue as this is from 2014. The errors I have searched and found no conclusive results. I checked for the void statements over and over and seen many repetitive stackoverflow questions. I have also tried restarting unity multiple times. More specific information on the errors: On Line 118,119,and 120 i get these two errors. Error CS0501: Method Must have return type. Error CS0501: 'PolygonGenerator.PolygonGenerator()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial. Anyways, my code is as follows: (also, please correct my comments and add more)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PolygonGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
// This first list contains every vertex of the mesh that we are going to render
public List<Vector3> newVertices = new List<Vector3>();
// The triangles tell Unity how to build each section of the mesh joining
// the vertices
public List<int> newTriangles = new List<int>();
// The UV list is unimportant right now but it tells Unity how the texture is
// aligned on each polygon
public List<Vector2> newUV = new List<Vector2>();

private float tUnit = 0.25f;
private Vector2 tStone = new Vector2(0, 0);
private Vector2 tGrass = new Vector2(0, 1);

// A mesh is made up of the vertices, triangles and UVs we are going to define,
// after we make them up we'll save them as this mesh
private Mesh mesh;

private int squareCount;
public byte[,] blocks; //0=air 1=rock, 2=grass

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //gets the mesh of the gameobject
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    //gets the x,y, and z values of the gameobject
    //writing x is easier than transform.position.x many times
    float x = transform.position.x;
    float y = transform.position.y;
    float z = transform.position.z;

    // defines what corners of the mesh to use for the four corners of the texture
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y));

    //clear anything within the meshes boundries
    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray(); //set the meshes vertecies to the new ones we just made
    mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
    mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray(); // applys uvs to the mesh
    mesh.Optimize(); //unity does some stuff
    mesh.RecalculateNormals(); // 
}

void GenSquare(int x, int y, Vector2 texture)
{
    //defines the vertexes of the new square
    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y, z));
    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y - 1, z));
    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y - 1, z));

    //without triangels all we have is points in space, no connections
    //these are added clockwise
    newTriangles.Add(squareCount * 4); // 0,0
    newTriangles.Add((squareCount * 4) +1); // 1,0
    newTriangles.Add((squareCount * 4)+3); // -1,0
    newTriangles.Add((squareCount * 4)+1); // 1,0
    newTriangles.Add((squareCount * 4)+2); // -1,1
    newTriangles.Add((squareCount * 4)+3); // -1,0

    // defines what corners of the mesh to use for the four corners of the texture
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * texture.x, tUnit * texture.y + tUnit));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * texture.x + tUnit, tUnit * texture.y + tUnit));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * texture.x + tUnit, tUnit * texture.y));
    newUV.Add(new Vector2(tUnit * texture.x, tUnit * texture.y));

    squareCount++;
}
void GenTerrain()
{
    blocks = new byte[10, 10];

    for (int px = 0; px < blocks.GetLength(0); px++)
    {
        for (int py = 0; py < blocks.GetLength(1); py++)
        {
            if (py >= 5)
            {
                blocks[px, py] = 2;
            }
            else if (py < 5)
            {
                blocks[px, py] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
void BuildMesh()
{
    for (int px = 0; px < blocks.GetLength(0); px++)
    {
        for (int py = 0; py < blocks.GetLength(1); py++)
        {

            if (blocks[px, py] == 1)
            {
                GenSquare(px, py, tStone);
            }
            else if (blocks[px, py] == 2)
            {
                GenSquare(px, py, tGrass);
            }

        }
    }
}

GenTerrain();
BuildMesh();
UpdateMesh();
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //clear anything within the meshes boundries
    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray(); //set the meshes vertecies to the new ones we just made
    mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
    mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray(); // applys uvs to the mesh
    mesh.Optimize(); //unity does some stuff
    mesh.RecalculateNormals(); // 

    squareCount = 0;
    newVertices.Clear();
    newTriangles.Clear();
    newUV.Clear();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenTerrain();
 BuildMesh();
UpdateMesh();`

These three method calls should be in a method, probably start or update. The computer thinks you're trying to define new methods here.

Comment: This was it. I was going crazy for nothing. Thanks!